# Testing and Production environment mixed in VPS CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, centos6, vps

I have a VPS on Godaddy with CentOs6 and I want to setup a testing environment for my project.

I got myself a free domain and set it up on my VPS with no problems. I uploaded my CakePHP Project to my testing environment with my new domain, so far so good.

The problems come when I realize that my testing environment which is running on the same server with a different domain and a different account is using my Production files. If a check my APP Global Variable it returns    `/home/production/public_html/app/` and it should return `/home/testing/public_html/app/`.

If I delete bootstrap.php I get an error that the file couldn't be found but if it is found the files that are used are the ones from my production environment.

I hope I've explained myself well.

Comment: I managed to solve this myself. I had forced https in beforeFilter of AppController. This redirection was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a caching problem. If you're using cakephp 2.x make sure that you clear the files in app/tmp.

Comment: I already tried that and didn't work. Funny thing is that if I delete bootstrap.php then CAKE will detect that the file is no there but if I delete database.php nothing happens. It is using the database.php from the production environment. I tried debugging index.php from webroot and the one in the root dir and the APP Constant is getting the right directory